# How to change the style of Title attribute tag?

Tags: html, title

I have this line on my code:

```
<i title="Música Anterior" class="icon icon-to-start prev"></i>
```

How I cant make it work like this:
[Title Attb](http://jsfiddle.net/tDQWN/129/)

Comment: Hey can you be more clear? Are you talking about data attribute?

Comment: @DeepakBandi I think op is talking about `tool-tip`.

Comment: You can use data-title instead of just title.

Comment: Yes, but I tryed data-title... Nothing happens.

Comment: tool-tip is the solution to what you are looking for. you can have a custom class where you can change the style of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot modify it.

in your jsFiddle links, the author uses data-title and then display it using css by creating new html element after it.

but you can create it using some css and javascript.